# can I restore 'ros-latest.list' that I mistook to remove

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I mistook to do:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm ros-latest.list
```

can i restore that list?

or is it no problem for using ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334981/can-i-restore-%27ros-latest.list%27-that-i-mistook-to-remove./) by [k's](https://answers.ros.org/users/46880/k%27s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> can i restore that list?

yes, just run this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Or use [one of the mirrors](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors) (perhaps [this one](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors#Japan)).

> or is it no problem for using ros?

For *running*: no it would not be a problem.

But for installing new packages or updates: yes it would be a problem, as `apt` would not be able to find the ROS package repositories any longer.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [k's](https://answers.ros.org/users/46880/k%27s/) on 2019-10-09**:
thank you for your help.
Do I need to reinstall ROS to do apt?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-10**:\

> Do I need to reinstall ROS to do apt?

No, I don't believe so.

Are you seeing any messages from `apt` that make you think so?

**Comment by [k's](https://answers.ros.org/users/46880/k%27s/) on 2019-10-11**:
I see.
No, not yet.